# PreTranslateMessage function not called in my class derived from cwinapp

Tags: c++, mfc

I have class derived from CWinApp, when I override PreTranslateMessage function in my class, I notice that the function is not invoked in any case. Any suggestions.

Comment: What are the cases you have tried?

Comment: u mean what keys I am trying to capture ?

Comment: I have used `CWnd::PreTranslateMessage`, but not sure how it will be used with CWinApp?

Comment: its CWinapp  further is derived from CWinThread which has PreTranslateMessage

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint inside `AfxPreTranslateMessage` and then seeing where it goes from there...

Comment: it doesnt hit threadcore's AfxPreTranslateMessage....:(

Comment: What Kind of application is it? Does this thread has any window? Is CWinThread;;PumpMesage called? Or Du you have you own mesage pump?

Comment: CWinThread;;PumpMesage not called

Comment: i didnt define any other message pump